# Provide a GUI application with environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

When using the command line, I can do something like

```
SET myvar=myval
myprogram.exe
```

to get `myprogram.exe` to see the environment variable `myvar`. Now, is there a way to make this happen also when I just click on `myprogram.exe` (say it is a GUI application)? I would like only `myprogram.exe` to see `myvar` so I would prefer to avoid setting it globally. Is there maybe a setting or a configuration file or something I can set around the .exe file so that I can get it properly running?

Comment: Yes, if you launch the GUI program from another program you can provide the child program with an environment block that you constructed. That's exactly what `cmd.exe` does.

Comment: So there is no workaround for this? Nothing I could use to avoid explicitly writing a launcher program?

Comment: You could write a batch file...

Comment: That is true, and then I would need to compile it to an exe to avoid showing a command line interface suddenly flashing. I can do all that, I just wanted to know if there wasn't an easier workaround first! :) Like, if there was a setting I didn't notice or so.

Comment: Does it have to be an environment variable? There are many alternative ways to convey info to an exe.